# Finder conceals network connections from lsof?

Tags: architecture, macos

If I use the Finder's Go->Connect to Server and connect to an smb/afs, I can see the connection in `netstat`.  But I can't see it in `lsof`.  I also use LittleSnitch, and it fails to detect outbound connections from the Finder.

Why is this?  Is there some sort of "Apple rootkit" that i'm not aware of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not the Finder making these connections—network filesystems are mounted within the kernel.  lsof doesn't list ports opened by the kernel.  There's nothing OS X specific here.

Comment: Heh.  It's all so obvious now.  Thanks.